# IOS App - Start/Stop Timer Like App - Suggestion Needed

Tags: ios, applications, software-recommendation

Hopefully this is the right place to ask as this is more about "looking for an appropriate iOS app".

I've got some noisy neighbors that do construction at all hours of the day and night. My city has noise ordinance restrictions and they are in clear violation. Reasonable conversation with them has failed on all accounts. They are perpetually working on their house and interior and from the looks of the place it doesn't seem like they'll be done anytime soon.

A bunch of my fellow neighbors are going to file a petition with the City in an effort to cite them for the noise problems. However, the petition requires a log of all the violations, and the more concise and detailed the log is, the more chance for further action.

In the past I've been using a Google Sheets document and when I hear the noises, I run over to my computer, fire up the document, note the start time and then I head back later and note the finish time. Or I'll use a piece of paper. It's a pest especially when it happens at 12:30AM and I'm in bed - I'm rather just close my window then climb out of bed and wait for my computer to boot up in order to keep a log of this stuff. With summer coming up, closing my window is going to be less of a solution.

Ideally I'd like to identify some sort of App that works like the iOS Clock's stop watch timer with the ability to add Notes. That way I can tell my neighbors to load this app, when they hear the noise push a "Start Timer" button, when the noises end push it again, and then add notes ("Banging and sawing with loud music"). Then we can export the results of this App to some sort of external document where we can compile a master list to submit to the city.

Reason I personally want it for iOS is that I have several older iphones laying around and would gladly keep one right by my bedside to use strictly as a logging service for this noise problem. My neighbors have iPhones as well so that's why I'd like the app to be iOS.

And yes, I realize I am probably over engineering this problem, but I figure having some sort of digital record of the neighbor's transgressions is better than scraps of paper scribbled on in the dark at 1AM that end up scattered around my nightstand.

Any ideas on what app I could use?

Edit: No, I don't need to actually record the noise. I just need a quick way to Start a timer and then an equally quick way to Stop the timer, so it makes an entry that I can annotate later. I'm thinking there has to be some sort of lap timer for runners that can be used to do what I'm thinking about.

Something like:

Entry #1) 5/23/18: Start Time: 11:30PM  Stop Time: 5/24/18 1:30AM.

Notes: Loud banging followed by sawing and shouting. (Note Added 5/24/18 7:30AM)

Comment: Are you also looking for this app to record the sound with timestamps?

Comment: I'm gonna +1 the question... even though I think your only viable solutions are... a) record audio 24/7 with timestamps or b) see if your local council has an app/web feature, however primitive.

Comment: No, sorry, I don't need to record the audio. Nothing that fancy. Imagine the Stopwatch Lap Timer, where you hit Start and it records a time, then Stop and it stops recording the time. Then when you hit Stop, it asks you to type in a note of some sort, and then it records all your Starts and Stops in a big list that you can export.

Comment: That way when I'm woken up at 12:30AM, I can grab the phone by my desk, hit Start to "record" a time stamp of 12:30AM, and when the sound stops I can hit "Stop" to record the time stamp of say 1:15AM. Then in the morning I can look at this list of times I did over night and annotate them.

Comment: How 'bout... "Hey Siri, make new note..." [nothing I've ever tried but wouldn't even need hands-on]

Comment: I understand that it's not necessarily what you've asked for as such but if you're already willing to over engineer it, a better solution may just be buying a device like a NodeMCU and hooking up a device that is activated above a certain noise level like [this](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/guide-for-microphone-sound-sensor-with-arduino/) and have it auto log the time etc. to a data sheet on a computer when the noise threshold is broken. This would allow for you to have a 24/7 log with no effort. A bit more coding could enable you to activate a microphone to record a snippet of audio too.